# Splitting dataset based on date in R, using library (lubridate)

Tags: r, date, slice, lubridate

While splitting a dataset I end up with the following error, and look for some advice to overcome it:

```
dt=read.csv("C:/xx/fData.csv")
testdata = dt[year(dt$date) < 2010,]
valid = dt[year(dt$date) > 2010,]

> training = dt[year(dt$date) < 2010,]
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
> testing = dt[year(dt$date) > 2010,]
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) :
```

ps: fData looks like

```
    | date   |   number
----------------------
1   |1/1/2011|  0
2   |1/2/2011|  0
```

Comment: It might be that you dt$date field is not of class `date`. Could you please try `class(dt$date)` to check this?

Comment: This might also happen, what is the year of this: `03-05-12`? Is it `2003` or `2012`? In such cases and similar you should define the format for `as.POSIXlt`. In your case maybe day and month.

Comment: @Edwin: `class(dt$date)` results in `factor`.

Comment: @Soheil: based on your example, `year` will be `2012` as the date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: @Soheil: based on your suggestion, how do you define the `format` for `as.POSIXlt`?

Comment: So Edwin was right, you should use `as.POSIXlt` to change the `class` of your date variable.

Comment: `dt$date <- as.POSIXct(dt$date, format="%m%d%Y")`

Comment: @Soheil: Thanks, the syntax works. However it looks like it's incompatible with the data slicing. I've checked the result of `dt[year(dt$date) < 2012,]` which does not produce the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the first part of your string is the month day and the second part is the month you should convert your string into a date format before calling the `year` function

```
dt$date <- as.Date(dt$date,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Many Thanks Edwin. The syntax works indeed. Furthermore, the splitting based on the date looks correct following a quick check.Cheers.